# FileNotFound after that I have created a jar file

Tags: java, jar, filenotfoundexception

after I created jar file I obtain this error in this line:

```
File inputFileCSV = new File(
                            System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\src\\Grafica\\home.csv");
```

Anyone can help me how I can avoid this?

Comment: Make sure the file exists

Comment: yes on eclips it works but when I create jar doesn't work

Comment: Maybe user.dir changes between when eclispe runs it and when it run from  a jar.

Comment: Try to log the value System.getProperty("user.dir") running with and without eclipse and compare the outputs.

Comment: Have you checked if the path shown in the FileNotFoundException message is the path you intend to use, the correct path?

Comment: ok the path is wrong, but how I can obtain the url  the resource in jar?

Comment: How I can load in my jar?

Comment: When I literally copy paste that line in a test class I do not get an error, because the creation of  a `File` object does not throw an exception if no file exists at the given path.  You need to provide more context here: are you using `java.io.File`?  What is the error you see?  Please show us the stack trace and the line where the exception is thrown, which is not the line you show in case you are using `java.io.File`

Answer (score 1):

"user.dir" is not user home directory, but directory where java was run from, where you started the JVM. So if you run two identical jar files from different dirs you will have different "user.dir" property value

Answer (score 0):

the folder that contains yourApp.jar should contains also  \src\Grafica\home.csv. Like this :
`--ParentFolder
   --App.jar
   --src
     --Grafica
       --home.csv`

Answer (score 0):

Organize your file in project like below

```
My Project
  |-src
    |-main
      |-java
      | |-MyPackage
      |   |-MyClass.java
      |-resources
        |-MyPackage
          |-home.csv
```

then access your file using like bellow

```
InputStream IS = MyClass.class
    .getResourceAsStream("home.csv");
```

Comment: It doesn't work. i need to load in my jar I try: getClass().getResource("/it_postal_codes.csv") but it gives me null